# Does the "Dawn Phenomenon" of blood sugar apply to non-diabetics?

Tags: diabetes, blood-tests

I bought myself a $15 blood sugar testing kit the other day because I've been experiencing some health things that are rare for me such as migraines (I rarely have had headaches my entire life) and a couple of other things that could be diabetes-related. A few of my relatives have gotten mild diabetes around the age I'm at so I figured better safe than sorry and why bother going to the doctor when I can get more information on my own first.

Anyway, last night I tested an hour after eating and my reading was 93, so I felt pretty good about that. This morning I tested when I woke up and it was 110, which I didn't feel good about. I know that hormones can make your blood sugar rise during the night but it seems like for non-diabetics, insulin should take care of that. I think the usual for fasting is 70-90. I did wake up about 30 minutes earlier than usual today but I don't think that should really matter. Does this mean I have prediabetes?

Comment: I'm sorry not to be more diplomatic, but the last line and a previous line ("why bother going to the doctor when I can get more information on my own first.") together seem amusing to me.

Comment: Talk to a diabetes specialist.